# Big O - Nested loops

Tags: big-o

```
void bar(int N){
  int c=0;
  for (int i=0; i<N*N; i++)
    for (int j= i; j< N; j++)
      c++;
}
```

The outer (and inner) loops above never get past N. Would this mean the Big O is N*N (N for the outer and N/2 for the inner)?

Comment: Why do you use `N*N` in the outer loop?  Just display `c` after the loops finish; that will tell you what you need to know.

Comment: the complexity is BigO(N^3)

Comment: @Tudor Vintilescu Can you explain your reasoning behind this?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a very bad reasoning, I didn't read your question well enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do this

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  for (int j = i; j < N; j++)
    …
```

you will iterate N times in the inner loop first, then N-1, then N-2, etc., which sums to N(N-1)/2. This loop runs in O(N²), that is the square of the outer loop.

In your case, your code is equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  for (int j = i; j < N; j++)
    c++;
```

since for every positive integer we have N² ≥ N and the compiler should be clever enough to notice that it makes no sense to continue running the outer loop if i is greater than N. So the complexity is indeed O(N²).

If you print `N` and `c` after your program runs, you will notice that when `N` gets doubled, `c` is almost multiplied by 4 (2²):

```
N = 1, c = 1
N = 2, c = 3
N = 4, c = 10
N = 8, c = 36
N = 16, c = 136
N = 32, c = 528
N = 64, c = 2080
N = 128, c = 8256
N = 256, c = 32896
N = 512, c = 131328
N = 1024, c = 524800
N = 2048, c = 2098176
```

Comment: Thanks for the transparent explanation!

Answer (score 0):

To know formally the number of iterations and the order of growth:

[image]